# How to install new packages for Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the proper procedure way to install new packages for Mathematica?

In particular, when you download [any](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/GraphTheory/HamiltonianGraph.nb) notebook from MathWorld, you are are given a [link](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4775) to Mathworld packages, which is are zip files with dozens of .m files

Where do they go?

Comment: Sometimes version inconsistencies drive me crazy while doing this. Am I the only one?

Comment: Not sure about version inconsistencies, but I spent last two hours trying to get my custom notation to work properly inside .m files, with no luck

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To have your packages that you've either downloaded or personally created visible to Mathematica, put them in `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`, or `$BaseDirectory/Applications` if you want them accessible to all users on your system. Alternatively, version 8.0.4 (and likely earlier) has a menu option: *File* -> *Install* which will do it for you. The menu option brings up the following dialog

[image: install dialog]

[image: install type drop-down displayed]

[image: item source drop-down displayed]

where the option "Install for this user only (name)" would install it under `$UserBaseDirectory` and the "for all users" option would install it under `$BaseDirectory`.

For more information on where *Mathematica* places everything I would read this [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaFileOrganization.html), and look through [directory operations functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/DirectoriesAndDirectoryOperations.html).

Answer (score 8):

If they are just temporary packages, it is often easier to load them from the current directory, but otherwise moving the files to anywhere on `$Path` (such as `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` as suggested by rcollyer) will work although some directories are autoloaded.

My usual solution is to have

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

as more or less the first line in all notebooks. I can then load packages from the notebook directory with `Needs["foo`"]`. For versioning, you can use the more verbose form of needs:

```
Needs["foo`","foo-001.m"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Under Windows it is often better to use `%AllUsersProfile%` directory instead of `%UserProfile%` for storing additional packages. [The following command](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExternalPrograms.html) gives the path to the corresponding directory under Windows:

```
First@ReadList["!cmd /C echo %AllUsersProfile%", 
   String] <> "\\Application Data\\Mathematica\\Applications"
```

P.S. I think [this](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/06fb7390bc9e8a17?hl=ru) and [this](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/cc6b03a3d87db5a4?hl=ru) answers of John Fultz are relevant.

Comment: Please add why you believe that this is better to your answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is a matter of personal preference. It is often easier to share all the beneficial changes for all accounts of multi-user computer, so you had no questions as to why the same work under one account, but it does not work under others.